# Can I use Android API's on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, voice-recognition

Is it possible to use Google voice recognition API for example, or other Android API's on Ubuntu?

Or is it better to learn and use them on Android for projects?

Comment: What do you mean by use? What is you target?

Comment: You could install Android x86 instead of Ubuntu

Comment: Maps, Drive, Speech, etc are not limited to Android...

Comment: @Bevor: I mean using google voice recognition, or google map in ubuntu instead of Android

Comment: @cricket_007: I like to use ARM-based boards like raspberry PI

Comment: @cricket_007: how can I use them on Linux? can you introduce a reference or some keywords for searching and learn?

Comment: Also I like to know, if I use speech or maps on linux, will this reduce the performance compare to Android?

Comment: I trust your abilities to search elsewhere to find at least NodeJS or Python examples of those API... And Android runs on Linux, so your question doesn't make sense. And high end phones are more powerful than a Pi, however using most Google API really is not resource intensive